# Different Registration Forms for different registration

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have 5 type of users, for each user i need different registration form with different fields. Is there any possible in Joomla 2.5 to have different registration form for different users. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use this component for your joomla 2.5 website [ExtendedReg](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303)

(OR) trying to create own Component. Otherwise to edit the joomla user register component

Answer (score 1):

Make your own profile plugin by copying the example one that is in the core.  Put the different forms you need in the profiles folder. In the plugin itself write the code to make the right forms show up for the right people.

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla docs give an example of exactly that use-case here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

You indeed have to create your own profile plugin as Elin was saying.